# How can I install NVidia driver from a .tar.gz?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install extra drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers)

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu, so please, don't suggest anything extremely advanced please.

I downloaded my driver from the NVidia website, and I have a .tar.gz. I extracted it in the terminal, went to where it was extracted, and input

```
./config
```

like I was told to, but it returned with 'no such file or directory exists'. Until I install the driver, my resolution will be stuck at 640x480, so please, someone help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JorgeCastro - I don't believe this was a duplicate. He's asking how to install the driver manually, not how to use Additional Drivers. On my laptop, the additional drivers versions of NVidia were garbage, so I used the newer one from the NVidia website.

Comment: As far as I can tell all the nvidia downloads are .run files, not tarballs..

Comment: He probably picked the FreeBSD package.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to System Settings -> Additional Drivers to install your driver. If no driver is listed there, chances are there is no proprietary Nvidia available for your version of Ubuntu.

Comment: So...what? I can't use Ubuntu then? Because I downloaded the driver from NVidia for Ubuntu, if it's available to Ubuntu on the NVidia website, how can you say it's not available?

Comment: Have you read my question? Is it available in Additional Drivers, yes or not? What type of graphics card do you have?

Comment: Calm down, both of you. @John Installing via the additional drivers dialogue is recommended, because it saves inexperienced users a lot of work in terminal. There is also a manual for installing the driver from the Nvidia website, like you were attempting to do: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaManual If you have already configured your system for the nvidia driver you could also try to install the necessary package from terminal manually (it would most likely be `nvidia-current`). But but that's more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

The community documentation provides a guide on [how to install the Nvidia drivers from the website](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaManual), but it's not recommended as it is extremely advanced like you said.

Usually if a matching card is found, the drivers will be available for installation, which is the safest way, but you can also force to install the necessary packages and configure them manually, again this is more advanced and not recommended.